# Laravel, what can each() function do?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have no specific work to do, just want to know what each() can do.
I have googled, and saw this post: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1380
It says

> each is there to perform some operations on all items, that's all
>   there is to it and that is what each is already doing.

What are the operations?

Comment: "The operations" are literally anything you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`each`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-each) method will iterate over items in the collection and allow you to execute code on each item. The difference between `each` and `map` is that while `each` simply iterates through the values, `map` *replaces* the value with whatever is returned in the callback. The documentation for `each` is found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-each). If you want to look at the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L203).

> The each method iterates over the items in the collection and passes
> each item to a callback. If you would like to stop iterating through
> the items, you may return false from your callback.

```
$users->each(function($user, $key) {
     $user->update(['last_login' => Carbon::now()]);         
});
```

The "some operations" you are inquiring about is the callback. In this case the callback/operation is:

```
function($user, $key) {
    $user->update(['last_login' => Carbon::now()]);         
}
```

This will update all the users in the collection's last login to the current time. Additionally, if you have a method on the `User` model named `updateLogin`

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function updateLogin()
    {
        $this->update(['last_login' => Carbon::now()]);
    }
}
```

You can actually just do the following with a collection of `$users`:

```
$users->each->updateLogin();
```

You can read about that [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#higher-order-messages):

> Collections also provide support for "higher order messages", which
> are short-cuts for performing common actions on collections.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the official laravel documentation: [Laravel 5.4 Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-each)

It states, that `The each method iterates over the items in the collection and passes each item to a callback`.

So for each item in the collection, it calls a function or does `something`. What that something is, is up to you to decide.

For example, the following snippet dumps every element in the collection:

```
$collection = $collection->each(function ($item, $key) {
    var_dump($item);
});
```

But you could also (for example) add it to a database or what ever comes to your mind.